# Custom sender email address for specific WooCommerce product

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a WooCommerce shop and it sends emails on every product order submission. I need to change the sender email address just for specific products into a custom address.

Already I am trying to achieve this using this code snippet to no avail:

```
add_filter('wp_mail_from', 'new_mail_from');

function new_mail_from($old) {
    return 'nombre@tudominio.es';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this filter:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', function( $recipient, $object ){
  if($conditional){
    $recipient = 'modified-recipient@gmail.com';
  }
  return $recipient;
});
```

Comment: but how add the conditionality for specific product ?

Comment: and i neet play this filter for : wp_mail_from, no woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order :(